# Facebook single sign-on not redirecting back to my application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have a scenario where Facebook application is installed in the device but not logged in by the user.
Now when I try to login throw my application its taking me to the Facebook applications login screen, After login its asking me to allow/block. Now Ideally It should take me back to my application but its not, It stays into the Facebook app.

Its working fine if the user is already logged in to the Facebook App.

If anyone has any idea on this issue please help...
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch Authentication events in AuthListener and then return to your activity through finish.

```
    /* AuthListener Methods */
@Override
public void onAuthFail(String error) {
    Log.e(TAG, "AuthFailed: " + error);
    this.finish();
}

@Override
public void onAuthSucceed() {
    Log.e(TAG, "AuthSucceed");
    this.finish();

}
```